# How to design http connection to database in concurrent environment (static variable or not)

Tags: java, http, amazon-web-services, asynchronous, concurrency

I am using dynamodb from amazon web services as my database. The client providd by AWS uses http to make the requests to the database. This code will be on a server which will accept requests from users and send it over to dynamodb. I had a few questions how to design this then.

Since this is a server accepting many requests I am using the async client http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/AmazonDynamoDBAsyncClient.html instead of the sync because I don't want for every request to block and instead I will wait for a future to return (better performance). Is it best to make this client static?

```
public class Connection {

    AmazonDynamoDBAsyncClient client;
    static DynamoDB dynamoDB;

    public Connection(){

        client = new AmazonDynamoDBAsyncClient(new ProfileCredentialsProvider());
        dynamoDB = null;

    }

    public void setConnection(String endpoint){
        client.setEndpoint(endpoint);
        dynamoDB = new DynamoDB(client);
    }


    public DynamoDB getConnection(){
        return dynamoDB;
    }

}
```

Then to call this static variable from main:

```
public class Main{

    Connection c;
    DynamoDB con;

            public  Main() throws Exception {

                try {
          c = new Connection();
          c.setConnection("http://dynamodbserver:8000");
          con = c.getConnection(); 
          //Do stuff with the connection now
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                     System.err.println("Program failed:");
                     System.err.println(e.getMessage());
                 }
```

Is this a good approach? What will happen if two users are requesting to use the static variable at the same time (I am using a framework called vertx so this program will run on a single thread, but there will be multiple instances of this program)?

Comment: Connection variables should never be static and they should rarely even be class members. They should almost always be local method variables.

Answer (score 1):

You should not set the connection as static member, Also the way you are setting endpoints of your connection is:

- not thread safe
- may lead to race condition

> Endpoints should be setup at the time of AmazonDynamoDBAsyncClient
>   construction and then this Async client should be used in the DynamoDB
>   construction. Please also refer to the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/AmazonWebServiceClient.html#setEndpoint(java.lang.String)).

Why don't you use the SDK provided with AWS for [dynamoDb](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/AboutJava.html)? It will take care of connection management for you in a thread safe manner.

On a side note, If you still want to roll out your own solution for connection management, I would recommend that you use a Dependecy Injection framework. I would highly recommend [google-guice](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki).

**Here is the sample code of DI through guice.**

```
public class DynamoDBProvider implements Provider<DynamoDB> {
  // Notice that endpoint is set at the time of client construction and the
  // get() method provides an instance of DynamoDb.
  // In another configuration class, we define that DynamoDb will be
  // served under singleton scope, so you will have a single instance.
  private final AmazonDynamoDBAsyncClient asyncClient;

  @Inject
  public DatabaseTransactionLogProvider(
      ProfileCredentialsProvider creds,
      @Named("Endpoint") String endpoint) { 
    this.asyncClient = new AmazonDynamoDBAsyncClient(creds);
    // endpoint is a configuration so it must also be injected to the provider.
    this.setEndpoint(endPoint);
  }

  public DynamoDb get() {
    return new DynamoDB(asyncClient);
  }
}
```

**This is how you ensure your connection instance is served as singleton.**

```
public class DynamoDBModule extends AbstractModule {

    protected void configure() {
       bind(Dynamodb.class).toProvider(DynamoDbProvider.class).in(Singleton.class);
    }
}
```

> Learning DI through guice or any other framework will require some
>   effort but it will go a a long way in making your code maintainable
>   and unit testable. Please be aware to utilize the benefits of DI, you
>   will have to refactor your project so that all depedencies are
>   injected.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Am I not using the SDK already? Classes such as  AmazonDynamoDBAsyncClient come from AWS SDK. I am using http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/JavaDocumentAPIWorkingWithTables.html as a reference for my code. In these guides though they use the sync client, but I prefer to use async. I am now a little confused as to if I am using the SDK? I much prefer to use what Amazon provides instead of making my own solution.

Comment: I checked the documentation page of AsynClient you posted in the question. The **overview** section states that the Aysnc interface is a low level API and Amazon SDK does connection management for you transparently. I assumed that SDK is different, I do not have AWS account so cannot confirm if what i understood is correct. There are some code samples, which i do not have access to can you verify if they use the same API as mentioned in the question. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/SettingUpTestingSDKJava.html

Answer (score -1):

static would be good since it is shared by all connection instance. but you can further improve the code by introducing singleton design pattern for connection class so that only one connection instance will be created and used for serve all the requests.

Comment: `static` would be atrocious given that he may have 'two users ... requesting to use the static variable at the same time'.